# Convert from Blender to Ogre3D

Tags: blender, ogre

I just finished to setup Blender so it can export to `Ogre`.  When I am exporting I get a bunch of `mesh` files and a `scene` file.

I am loading the model that the Ogre SDK provides and it works like so:

```
mSceneMgr->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));

// Create an Entity
Ogre::Entity* ogreHead = mSceneMgr->createEntity("Head", "ogrehead.mesh");

// Create a SceneNode and attach the Entity to it
Ogre::SceneNode* headNode = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("HeadNode");
headNode->attachObject(ogreHead);

// Create a Light and set its position
Ogre::Light* light = mSceneMgr->createLight("MainLight");
light->setPosition(20.0f, 80.0f, 50.0f);
```

What's happening is that it loads a single `mesh` file and that's it.

This is the Blender export output:

[image]

What do I need to do from here in order to load my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want to achieve.

Currently you have created a scene in blender containing multiple parts that together result in your BlackHawk helicopter. If you just need a single object in Ogre, you can combine the elements inside Blender into one object, export that and use the same loading code as before (using the new *.mesh* file name of course).

If you want the individual parts to stay independent, you will have to load them into Ogre one by one or use one of the many DotScene loaders (e.g. [this one](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/New+DotScene+Loader) or [that one](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=RapidXML+Dotscene+Loader) or [the one](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=DotScene+Loader+with+User+Data) that also handles user data) and point it to your *"BlackHawk.scene"* file (which should reference all helicopter parts).

Comment: first, thank you so much for your reply! when i am trying to use your first option to load the .scene file i get compilation error from visual c 2010 :  1>  tinyxmlparser.cpp
1>  tinyxmlerror.cpp
1>  tinyxml.cpp
1>  tinystr.cpp

Comment: Well, there is no way that we can help to fix that issue with that few information. Much more details needed, probably an own thread to keep it to prevent confusion.